# Override pluggable functions in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, pluggable, activation

WordPress has a file called `pluggable.php` which contains a list of functions you can override in your plugin.

The problem I am facing (I am overriding `wp_authenticate`) is for each blog in my network I try to activate this plugin, I get:

> failure, can't re-declare wp_authenticate which was previously declared in pluggable.php

This somewhat defeats the ease of use, I have to comment the function in the plugin file, activate the plugin, un-comment the function for it to work properly.

What is the correct way to do it?
Can't expect users who download plugin to do all that.

I am using 3.5 + multi-site configuration

Comment: have you wrapped the function in `if(!function_exists())` as in the [example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions#Example)? show us your code.

Comment: Why do I need to wrap? I want my function to ALWAYS take precedence. Or, do I have towrap it all the time and plugins are loaded first?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your function in `if( ! function_exists( 'wp_authenticate' ) )` to get rid of the error and successfully activate your plugin:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'wp_authenticate' ) ){
    function wp_authenticate(){}
}
```

This is necessary because in the context of activating a plugin, the function *does* already exist, only after it is activated will your plugin load first and override the original in `pluggable.php`. Plugins are activated in a sandbox to capture any fatal errors which may prevent activation and successful recovery to a working state.

Answer (score 0):

But if your plugin needs a function in pluggables.php (like wp_safe_redirect), then you must manually include_once that file. Otherwise, you get an 'call to undefined function' error for a function that is in that pluggables.php file.

I did it this way

```
    if ( !function_exists('wp_safe_redirect')) {
        require_once (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
     }
```

Replace the function name (in this case 'wp_safe_redirect') with your needed function.

Perhaps this will save someone the several hours I spent trying to figure that error.